# Expressing $\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}$ as a polynomial in $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $\zeta$ be an $n$-th root of unity and let $\chi:=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$. Then $\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}=P_k(\chi)$ where $P_k\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is a polynomial not depending on $n$. For example we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}&=&\chi^2-2,
\qquad&\text{ so }&\qquad
P_2&=&X^2-2,\\
\zeta^3+\zeta^{-3}&=&\chi^3-3\chi,
\qquad&\text{ so }&\qquad
P_3&=&X^3-3X,\\
\zeta^4+\zeta^{-4}&=&\chi^4-4\chi^2+2,
\qquad&\text{ so }&\qquad
P_4&=&X^4-4X^2+2,\\
\zeta^5+\zeta^{-5}&=&\chi^5-5\chi^3+5\chi,
\qquad&\text{ so }&\qquad
P_5&=&X^5-5X^3+5,\\
\zeta^6+\zeta^{-6}&=&\chi^6-6\chi^4+9\chi^2+18,
\qquad&\text{ so }&\qquad
P_6&=&X^6-6X^4+9X^2+18.
\end{eqnarray*}
It isn't hard to see that $P_{ab}=P_a\circ P_b=P_b\circ P_a$ for all positive integers $a$ and $b$, and that we have a recurrence relation
$$P_a=X^a-\sum_{i=1}\binom{a}{i}P_{a-2i},$$
where we take the convention that $P_k=0$ for all $k<0$, and $P_0=1$. My question is:

> Is there a simple explicit expression for $P_k$?

Comment: This may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: @SeewooLee Can you turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

As I said, [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) are exactly what you said.